# Treat date in MySQL as being in last 12 months regardless of the actual year stored

Tags: mysql

I want to run a `SELECT` query on `table` which picks up the date stored in the `year_end` field and automatically treats it as being that occurrence of the date in the last 12 months.

I.e.: today is May 14th so:

If I have `2012-01-01` then I want that unchanged

If I have `2010-05-05` then I want `2012-05-05`

If I have `2012-10-10` then I want `2011-10-10`

Any ideas on the `SELECT` I need please?

Comment: How will you treat date differences in leap years?

Comment: 29th Feb only needs to be treated as 28th Feb, or 1st March.  It doesn't matter so long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
select
concat(yr,'-',if(leapyear=0,if(right(dt,5)='02-29','03-01',
right(@mydate,5)),right(@mydate,5))) dttm
from
(
    select concat(if(my_md > md,yr -1,yr),'-',my_md) dt,yr,my_md,
    IF(MOD(yr,4)>0,0,IF(MOD(yr,100),1,(MOD(yr,400)=0))) leapyear FROM
    (select substr(date(@mydate),6) my_md) AA,
    (select substr(date(now()),6) md,year(now()) yr) BB
) A;
```

Here are the three dates you chose as examples + 2 leap year dates

```
set @mydate = '2012-01-01';
set @mydate = '2010-05-05';
set @mydate = '2012-10-10';
set @mydate = '2008-02-29';
set @mydate = '2012-02-29';
```

Here they are executed

mysql> set @mydate = '2012-01-01';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> select
    -> concat(yr,'-',if(leapyear=0,if(right(dt,5)='02-29','03-01',right(@mydate,5)),right(@mydate,5))) dttm
    -> from
    -> (
    ->     select concat(if(my_md > md,yr -1,yr),'-',my_md) dt,yr,my_md,
    ->     IF(MOD(yr,4)>0,0,IF(MOD(yr,100),1,(MOD(yr,400)=0))) leapyear FROM
    ->     (select substr(date(@mydate),6) my_md) AA,
    ->     (select substr(date(now()),6) md,year(now()) yr) BB
    -> ) A;
+------------+
| dttm       |
+------------+
| 2012-01-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @mydate = '2010-05-05';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    -> concat(yr,'-',if(leapyear=0,if(right(dt,5)='02-29','03-01',right(@mydate,5)),right(@mydate,5))) dttm
    -> from
    -> (
    ->     select concat(if(my_md > md,yr -1,yr),'-',my_md) dt,yr,my_md,
    ->     IF(MOD(yr,4)>0,0,IF(MOD(yr,100),1,(MOD(yr,400)=0))) leapyear FROM
    ->     (select substr(date(@mydate),6) my_md) AA,
    ->     (select substr(date(now()),6) md,year(now()) yr) BB
    -> ) A;
+------------+
| dttm       |
+------------+
| 2012-05-05 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @mydate = '2012-10-10';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    -> concat(yr,'-',if(leapyear=0,if(right(dt,5)='02-29','03-01',right(@mydate,5)),right(@mydate,5))) dttm
    -> from
    -> (
    ->     select concat(if(my_md > md,yr -1,yr),'-',my_md) dt,yr,my_md,
    ->     IF(MOD(yr,4)>0,0,IF(MOD(yr,100),1,(MOD(yr,400)=0))) leapyear FROM
    ->     (select substr(date(@mydate),6) my_md) AA,
    ->     (select substr(date(now()),6) md,year(now()) yr) BB
    -> ) A;
+------------+
| dttm       |
+------------+
| 2012-10-10 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @mydate = '2008-02-29';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    -> concat(yr,'-',if(leapyear=0,if(right(dt,5)='02-29','03-01',right(@mydate,5)),right(@mydate,5))) dttm
    -> from
    -> (
    ->     select concat(if(my_md > md,yr -1,yr),'-',my_md) dt,yr,my_md,
    ->     IF(MOD(yr,4)>0,0,IF(MOD(yr,100),1,(MOD(yr,400)=0))) leapyear FROM
    ->     (select substr(date(@mydate),6) my_md) AA,
    ->     (select substr(date(now()),6) md,year(now()) yr) BB
    -> ) A;
+------------+
| dttm       |
+------------+
| 2012-02-29 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @mydate = '2012-02-29';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    -> concat(yr,'-',if(leapyear=0,if(right(dt,5)='02-29','03-01',right(@mydate,5)),right(@mydate,5))) dttm
    -> from
    -> (
    ->     select concat(if(my_md > md,yr -1,yr),'-',my_md) dt,yr,my_md,
    ->     IF(MOD(yr,4)>0,0,IF(MOD(yr,100),1,(MOD(yr,400)=0))) leapyear FROM
    ->     (select substr(date(@mydate),6) my_md) AA,
    ->     (select substr(date(now()),6) md,year(now()) yr) BB
    -> ) A;
+------------+
| dttm       |
+------------+
| 2012-02-29 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

Probbaly inefficient query, regarding performance, but it works:

```
SELECT 
    dateX + INTERVAL ( YEAR(CURDATE())
                     - YEAR(dateX) 
                     - ( ( MONTH(dateX), DAY(dateX) ) 
                       > ( MONTH(CURDATE()), DAY(CURDATE()) )
                       )
                     ) YEAR 
      AS calc_date
FROM 
    tableX ;
```

You can test it [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a0b/1). Another version, slightly more readable:

```
SELECT 
    d + INTERVAL ( now.yy - t.yy - ((t.mm, t.dd) > (now.mm, now.dd))
                 ) YEAR 
      AS calc_date
FROM
    ( SELECT 
          dateX        AS d 
        , YEAR(dateX)  AS yy
        , MONTH(dateX) AS mm
        , DAY(dateX)   AS dd           
      FROM tableX
    ) AS t
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT 
          YEAR(CURDATE())  AS yy
        , MONTH(CURDATE()) AS mm
        , DAY(CURDATE())   AS dd            
    ) AS now ;
```